# Why does ITopologicalOperator2 .ConstructUnion produce a somehow invalid polygon?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#, arcgis-engine, wpf

I try to add a single buffer around the shape of the selected features. So I step through each selected feature and add it's shape to a `GeometryBag`. With `ITopologicalOperator2.ConstructUnion` I create a union geometry. But when I use this geometry to add an element, nothing appears after `Refresh`.

The code part for adding an element does work, when I directly assign `element.Geometry = feature.Shape`. So `ConstructUnion` seems to fail here. Any ideas why?

I already found out, that I have to simplify the shapes before adding it to `GeometryBag` and to set the `SpatialReference` on the `GeometryBag` before.

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IGraphicsContainer graphicsContainer = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IGraphicsContainer)activeView.FocusMap;

ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IEnumFeature enumFeature = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IEnumFeature)map.FeatureSelection;
enumFeature.Reset();
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeature feature = enumFeature.Next();

IGeometryBag geoBag = new GeometryBagClass();
geoBag.SpatialReference = activeView.FocusMap.SpatialReference;
IGeometryCollection geometriesToUnion = geoBag as IGeometryCollection;
while (!(feature == null))
{
  ITopologicalOperator2 shape = feature.ShapeCopy as ITopologicalOperator2;
  shape.IsKnownSimple_2 = false; // see nef001's answer
  shape.Simplify();
  geometriesToUnion.AddGeometry(shape as IGeometry);
  feature = enumFeature.Next();
}

IPolygon poly = new PolygonClass();
resultPolygon.SpatialReference = activeView.FocusMap.SpatialReference; // see Petr Krebs's comment
ITopologicalOperator2 resultPolygon = poly as ITopologicalOperator2;
resultPolygon.ConstructUnion(geometriesToUnion as IEnumGeometry);
IFillShapeElement fillShapeElement = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.PolygonElementClass();
fillShapeElement.Symbol = fillSymbol;
ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IElement element = (IElement)fillShapeElement;
topologicalOperator = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.ITopologicalOperator)resultPolygon;
//element.Geometry = topologicalOperator.Buffer(distance);
element.Geometry = resultPolygon as IGeometry; // To make sure, it's not the Buffering that goes wrong
graphicsContainer.AddElement(element, 0);
```

**Update:** 
To address Petr Krebs suggestions

- I changed the assignment of `geometriesToUnion.AddGeometry` to `feature.ShapeCopy`.
- I changed the assignment of `element.Geometry` to resultPolygon instead of the
  buffer output.

Both didn't help.

- For testing I use a single layer where I select three polygon features. So the are all  polygons and have the same SpatialReference.
- `resultPolygon.IsEmpty` after `ConstructUnion` is false.

**Update 2**

- Regarding Nef001's answer I added `shape.IsKnownSimple_2 = false;` but it didn't change the result.

**Update 3**

- Regarding Petr's answer I set the spatial reference before `Union()` but it didn't help.

Comment: On your initial feature selection that is being enumerated have you verified that only one type of geometry is selected (e.g. just polygons)?

Comment: @AHigh: Yes, I do make sure that there is only one geometry type. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Does creating the element with polygon geometry directly from, say, the first selected polygon work?

Comment: @Petr, do you mean without using `ConstructUnion`? When I directly assign `element.Geometry = feature.Shape` it does work, as I pointed out. (made that more clear in the question) That's why I think it has to be something with `ConstructUnion`.

Comment: As an off-chance -- since your geometries don't appear to be empty -- what is your graphicsContainer defined as?

Comment: I also might try casting resultPolygon to a new Polygon after the .ConstructUnion(). IPolygon newThing = resultPolygon as IPolygon; and then dealing with the higher -level geometry object. I don't know if that will make a difference but it's worth a shot.

Comment: @AHigh: The `GraphicsContainer` is a casted  `IActiveView.FocusMap` (added to question). Casting `resultPolygon` to an `IPolygon` didn't help.

Comment: Try creating your resultPolygon as new PolygonClass() and set its spatial reference before calling ConstructUnion

Comment: `new Polygon` and `new PolygonClass` has exactly the same effect, but setting the spatial reference prior to calling `Union` is a good idea!

Comment: Petr, yes the SR thing is clear from the documentation

Comment: @Petr: I added the spatial reference - no change. I think of making a test project I could share. Would that help?

Comment: It could, in case you also provide some sample data (e.g. in a file geodatabase).

Answer (score 1):

ESRI Documentation says that this method does not support GeometryBags.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m000003vn000000

Comment: He is not using it on a geometry bag, but is using the GeometryBag coclass as a convenient implementation of IEnumGeometry.

Comment: Petr, it doesn't mater what interface he is sending into the ConstructUnion method.  The fact that the base class is a GeometryBag will prevent this from working.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. He is calling ITopologicalOperator.ConstructUnion on `resultPolygon`, which is a `Polygon` instance. The argument to `ConstructUnion` is an `IEnumGeometry` (implemented by a GeometryBag), but none of the geometries in this enumeration is a geometry bag. Thus, there are no geometry bags upon which ConstructUnion operates.

Comment: Hmm..  Seems I misread the documentation and made the assumption that the constructUnion wouldn't take a geometry bag as an argument rather than the fact that enumeration couldn't contain a geometry bag.  My mistake.

Comment: Agreed it is terrible wording on ESRI's part. As long as the individual elements of the geometry collection are not GeometryBags that shouldn't be the problem. In fact their own samples do it: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000009t000000

Comment: Guys, I personally do not find the wording confusing at all. They are saying that you can only use it on high-level geometries, but cannot use it for geometry bags, which I believe programmers would easily try. The method takes an IEnumGeometry interface as an argument, which like any other interface is merely a clear contract for geometry enumeration. As such, it makes no difference which class implements that contract, and GeometryBag just so happens to be convenient list of geometries (implements IGeometryCollection), which you can also enumerate since it implements IEnumGeometry as well.

Answer (score 1):

Few things to try:

1. Make sure the selection enumerator is either non-recycling (see [IEnumFeatureSetup](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000228000000), or otherwise copy the feature geometries prior to adding them to the geometry bag (via [IFeature.ShapeCopy](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000331000000)).
2. Make sure all the input geometries, as well as the newly created Polygon have the same spatial reference.
3. Make sure all the input geometries are polygons, which you seem to be assuming.
4. Check that it is not actually the subsequent buffer operation that prevents your code snippet from working as expected.

Comment: After every operation (Union and Buffer), check whether the resulting geometry is empty (IGeometry.IsEmpty) or not..

Comment: Thanks for the hints. 1.) I changed the asignment to ShapeCopy, but with no result. 2. + 3.) For testing I use a single layer where I select three polygon features. 4.) For testing I directly used the `resultPolygon` instead of the `Buffer` output as element geometry, but it didn't helped. And 5.) `resultPolygon.IsEmpty` is false.

Answer (score 0):

I think calling Simplify() on ITopologicalOperator does nothing unless you first set IsKnownSimple to false.

Try adding to your code before the call to Simplify:

```
shape.IsKnownSimple_2 = false;
```

See the following Remarks in the documentation for [ITopologicalOperator.Simplify()](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriGeometry/ITopologicalOperator_Simplify.htm) method:

> **Remarks**
>   This method first looks at the ITopologicalOperator::IsKnownSimple flag before starting processing. If the flag is 'true' then operation is interrupted and the geometry is considered simple. If the flag is 'false' then the geometry consistency is checked and the geometry is updated as needed.

Comment: Thanks. I added it to both my source and the question. Unfortunately it didn't help with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think code in question successfully builds at the moment..I made a few edits..Cast the resultpolygon to ITopologicalOperator2 and added a Type.Missing object parameter to the AddGeometry function..It works for me.

```
IGeometryCollection geometriesToUnion = geoBag as IGeometryCollection;
object missing = Type.Missing;
while (!(feature == null))
{
    ITopologicalOperator2 shape = feature.ShapeCopy as ITopologicalOperator2;
    shape.IsKnownSimple_2 = false; // see nef001's answer
    shape.Simplify();

    geometriesToUnion.AddGeometry(shape as IGeometry, ref missing, ref missing);
    feature = enumFeature.Next();
}

IPolygon poly = new PolygonClass();
poly.SpatialReference = activeView.FocusMap.SpatialReference;
ITopologicalOperator2 topologicalOperator;
topologicalOperator = poly as ITopologicalOperator2;

topologicalOperator.ConstructUnion(geometriesToUnion as IEnumGeometry);
IFillShapeElement fillShapeElement = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.PolygonElementClass();
ISimpleFillSymbol simpleFillSymbol = new SimpleFillSymbolClass();
fillShapeElement.Symbol = simpleFillSymbol;
IElement element = (IElement)fillShapeElement;

topologicalOperator = (ITopologicalOperator2)poly;
element.Geometry = topologicalOperator.Buffer(10);
graphicsContainer.AddElement(element, 0);
```

Comment: The need for adding Type.Missing arguments is dependent on the version of C# compiler you use. With C# 4.0 and newer compiler, it is not necessary. Note that C# 4 compiler can still target lower versions of .NET, e.g. .NET 3.5.